# how can i highlight text within textarea reactjs bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

here im using this jquery highlight_within_textarea [link](https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/)
here is my textarea

```
<textarea className="form-control"
      spellcheck="false"
      placeholder="enter"
       id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows={4} 
       style={{fontSize: '20px',strong:{
        color:'#b1b1b1',
       fontSize:18,
      }}}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       value={this.state.input}
       />
```

here is my react handleChange updateHighlights

```
    handleChange(text){
    this.setState({input:text.target.value});
     this.updateHighlights();
  }
  updateHighlights() {
    $('#exampleFormControlTextarea1').highlightWithinTextarea({
      highlight: [
        {
            highlight: 'strawberry',
            className: 'red'
        },
        {
            highlight: 'blueberry',
            className: 'blue'
        },
        {
            highlight: /ba(na)*/gi,
            className: 'yellow'
        }
    ]
  });
  }
```

Expected output 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F3JN.png)
what I'm getting 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYc0D.png)